# Google Fused Location API Last known location with a 5 sec Time Constraint?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-client

I am following this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html . Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG,"last location"+ mLastLocation);     //logs correctly

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            mLongitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        buildGoogleApiClient();

        //////////////////////////////If activity was started with a bundle
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            bundle = getIntent().getExtras().getBundle("bundle");
            if (bundle != null) {
                int size = bundle.getInt("size", 0);
                Log.d("MyLogs", "From Intent - " + bundle.getString("string"));
                array = new String[size];
                array = bundle.getStringArray("array");
                String hashtag = array[1];
                if (hashtag.indexOf("/") != -1) {
                    String[] parts = hashtag.split("/");
                    if (parts[1] != null) {
                        String part2 = parts[1];       //tracking_id
                        Map<String, Object> event = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                Log.i(TAG,"last location"+ mLastLocation);                                          // logs null

                        event.put("sticker_ID", part2);
                        event.put("device_ID",android_id);
                        event.put("Latitude",mLastLocation);
                        event.put("longitude",mLongitude);
                        // Adding it to tracking system
                        KeenClient.client().queueEvent("android-sample-button-clicks", event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    CountDownTimer CountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (millisUntilFinished / 1000 <= 3) {
                int time = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                if (time == 2) {

                    proImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_two);
                } else if (time == 1) {
                    proImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_one);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            proImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            takePicture();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        //other stuff {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePreview.class);
            if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                if (bundle != null)
                    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

}
```

Also I my manifest I have included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

There is a bunch of stuff I took out, but here is basically how I am handling the location getting. I build a googleApiClient, assign the lat and lon to parts of mLastLocation. And I send them into my tracking event. My activity by nature has only 5 seconds before it jumps into the next activity (see onPictureTaken). Its a countdown.

I think whats happening is that it simply cannot resolve the location in 5 seconds. Should 5 seconds be enough? Does this seem like it might be the issue? And if its not, is there any way for me to keep this task going even though the next activity has started? Then I can send in the data to the tracker on the next activity with some callback (on mLastLocation received successfully)?

Comment: So `onConnected()` is being called but `getLastLocation()` is returning null? `getLastLocation()` isn't a blocking call.

Comment: Im not sure. Its not giving any errors. Thus, it seems mLatitude and mLongitude are being returned, just returned with Null value. but all my location settings are turned on.

Comment: `getAltitude()`/`getLongitude()` return doubles which can't be `null`. Can you add a log statement or debug your app to see if `getLastLocation()` returns null?

Comment: oh wait it actually is logging mLastLocation correctly. looks like Location[fused 34.518380,-119.779084 acc=30 et=+56m23s29ms] . So its something about getting the lat and lon out of it and logging those that isn't working

Comment: also, mLatitude and mLongitude are logging just fine. Its something about how the get inserted into the the lines where they are logged that it returns null. hmm

Comment: So where do you actually use `mLatitude` and `mLongitude` after you get them from `onConnected()`? Where are you expecting them to be non-null?

Comment: I expect them to be non-null in all of the event.put lines in the onCreate method. I added log lines in the question that have comments on them to show that it is logging properly in the onConnected function, but not in the onCreate function

Comment: @ianhanniballake FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() IS a blocking call. I think you meant FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation() which returns a Task.

Answer (score 1):

The [Activity lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) shows that `onCreate()` is called, then `onStart()` is called. In your `onStart()`, you call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()`, which then asynchronously calls `onConnected()` once it is connected.

Therefore you will never have a valid location in `onCreate()` as it is not available until after `onConnected()` is called (which is well after `onCreate()` finishes).

You should move your code that requires a location to after you get a valid location.